# JavaScript - how to inject different implementation of function e.g. alert (sharing modules with web & Node.js server side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, implementation, inject

Situation: There is big number of JavaScript files. I want to run them on Node.js.

But there are several places where e.g. `alert()` is used, that causes Node.js to fail.

Of course, there is way to look into every file and add import like

`alert = require('console').log`

but that would stop those files working inn browser (on client side).

**Is there way to inject different implementation of `alert`?** That is to change/add function implementation without modifying sources?

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your code, write:

`global.alert = console.log;`

Answer (score 1):

**Basic version**

Inside a file `silentalert.js`

```
if(typeof global != "undefined"){
  global.alert = typeof console != "undefined" && console.log ? console.log.bind(this) : function(){};
}
```

Inside your NodeJS scripts:

```
require('./silentalert');
```

This code will print alert messages to `console.log` in NodeJS but will still use `alert` when run in the browser.

The next implementation offers a more generic approach.

---

**Cross-platform version**

Inside a file `silentalert.js`

```
var g           = typeof global != "undefined" ? global : (typeof window != "undefined") ? window : {};
var c           = typeof console != "undefined" && console.log ? console.log.bind(this) : function(){};
var _old        = g.alert;
var silentalert = function(activate){
  g.alert       = activate ? c : _old;
};
if(typeof module !== "undefined"){module.exports = silentalert;}
```

Inside a NodeJS script:

```
var silentalert = require('./silentalert');
silentalert(true); 
// or silentalert(typeof window == "undefined") if you just want to silent alert() on NodeJS
// your script...
silentalert(false);
```

You can even directly include silentalert.js inside an HTML page:

```
<script src="./silentalert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
silentalert(true);
// your script...
silentalert(false);
</script>
```

Note: If you need to support IE8 [`.bind` won't be available](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind) in that case replace:

```
var c = typeof console != "undefined" && console.log ? console.log.bind(this) : function(){};
```

with

```
var c = typeof console != "undefined" && console.log ? function(){console.log.apply(console, arguments);} : function(){};
```

Both scripts allows you to silent alerts in NodeJS while still being able to use them on the client-side.